# Navigator.onLine not working in Cordova.android

Tags: android, cordova

Navigator.onLine always seems to be true in Cordova Android. I tried both cordova-android 10 and 11. Turned off WIFI and bluetooth and turned on airplane mode. No joy. Works fine on iOS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you testing on device? If I inspect android webview from device and turn off network by using offline preset, navigator.onLine is false

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the plugin cordova.plugins.diagnostic

read the documentation here for usage https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#wifi-module